# Can I play sound from video if the screen is blank? iphone

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

In an iPhone app I'm working on, I am playing an mp4 video and I want to be able to listen to the sound of the video after I press the sleep button.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is possible only if you press the home button.

Then, you double press the home button again, the music controlling

is shown up. After that, you press the play button.

I don't think it will be any methods to do in the sleep mode.